# Swift CMMotionManager getting Roll, Pitch, Yaw to work

Tags: swift, cmmotionmanager

I am having difficulty getting the syntax right to return the roll, pitch, yaw in Swift correctly. The accelerometers all work fine but can't sort this one out. Here's the material code:

```
var roll: Double    = 0.0
var pitch: Double   = 0.0
var yaw: Double     = 0.0    
var manager         = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (rpyData: CMDeviceMotionHandler?, NSError) -> Void in self.outputRPY(rpyData!.deviceMotion)
     if(NSError != nil) {
          print("\(NSError)")
     }
   })
}

func outputRPY(data: CMDeviceMotion){
    roll    = data.attitude.roll
    pitch   = data.attitude.pitch
    yaw     = data.attitude.yaw
    rollLabel.text  = String(format: "%.2f°", roll)
    pitchLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f°", pitch)
    rollLabel.text  = String(format: "%.2f°", yaw)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter type should be a NSError? (Aka an optional) and in the body of your closure, you are comparing a type to a value.

In all, it should look like this:

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, err: NSError?) -> Void in 
    self.outputRPY(deviceMotion!)
    if(err != nil) {
        print("\(err)")
    }
}
```

You could also use optional binding to be more swifter... :)

```
if error = err {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

**Edit**:

After testing on my home machine, I realised that there was one more issue. `CMDeviceMotionHandler` declares the type of the closure (or function pointer, if you will). It is declared as:

```
public typealias CMDeviceMotionHandler = (CMDeviceMotion?, NSError?) -> Void
```

So your closure (or handler) should be like:

```
{ (deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // code goes here
}
```

Finally, your second parameter is making the identifier `NSError` refer to a variable, when it is already a type (which is legal). I personally wouldn't name it as such, since it can be easy confuse with the type `NSError`. Maybe you could perhaps name it `nserror`, which would avoid any confusion with the existing type.

The first code snippet should just copy-paste into your project.

Comment: The problem is fundamentally in the first line: The Gyro Accelerometer equivalent which I have working is: manager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (gyroData: CMGyroData?, NSError) -> Void in self.outputRotData(gyroData!.rotationRate)
            if (NSError != nil){
                print("\(NSError)")
            }
        })

Comment: What's the error the compiler is giving you? I also realised that my example was wrong, which may fix your problem. See the edit.

Comment: I have posted up a working solution which I suspect is what you were so kindly pushing me towards. Very many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that was throwing me is that the Roll, Pitch, Yaw appear to work differently from the accelerometers, gyros, magnetometers. Here's the fresh off the press code:

```
 var manager         = CMMotionManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {   
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval  = 0.2
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {(motionData: CMDeviceMotion?, NSError) -> Void in self.outputRPY(motionData!)
        if (NSError != nil){
            print("\(NSError)")
        }
    })
 }

 func outputRPY(data: CMDeviceMotion){
    let rpyattitude = manager.deviceMotion!.attitude
    roll    = rpyattitude.roll * (180.0 / M_PI)
    pitch   = rpyattitude.pitch * (180.0 / M_PI)
    yaw     = rpyattitude.yaw * (180.0 / M_PI)     
    rollLabel.text  = String(format: "%.2f°", roll)
    pitchLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f°", pitch)
    yawLabel.text   = String(format: "%.2f°", yaw)
}
```